# Guest user getting 'Unauthorized access' when displaying a "lightning-record-form" for case creation

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, guest-user

I followed this to give Guest User create `Case` access. Along with this given access to Record Type also and few other fields like Subject, Description, Origin.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386878&type=1

But Still while displaying the `lightning-record-form` on **LWR site**. The guest user is receiving `Unauthorized access` message.

LWC:

```
<lightning-record-form
        object-api-name={caseobject}
        fields={caseFields}
        onsuccess={handleCaseCreated} onsubmit={handleSubmit}>
</lightning-record-form>
```

---

JS

```
import CASE_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Case';
import SUBJECT_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Case.Subject';
import CONTACT_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Case.SuppliedPhone';
import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Case.SuppliedName';
import EMAIL_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Case.SuppliedEmail';
import DESCRIPTION_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Case.Description';


export default class TestLWRCaseCreate extends LightningElement {
    
    
    caseobject = CASE_OBJECT;

    caseFields = [NAME_FIELD, EMAIL_FIELD, SUBJECT_FIELD, CONTACT_FIELD, DESCRIPTION_FIELD];
    
    
        handleAccountCreated(event){
        const inputFields = this.template.querySelectorAll(
            'lightning-input-field'
        );
        if (inputFields) {
            inputFields.forEach(field => {
                field.reset();
            });
        }
    }

    handleSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        const fields = event.detail.fields;
        fields.Origin = 'Web';
        this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-form').submit(fields);

    }
    
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got It.

There is a setting in Administration view of workspace.

`Allow guest users to access public APIs`

This needs to be checked so that Guest user will be able to utilize `lightning-record-form` to create records.

[image]